# .add() .set() on m2m relation django not working as expected

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have some troubles with m2m relation in Django. I'm working on sqlite db local and mysql on production.

Locally everything is working as I expected (with shell and admin panel). But I have issues on production. Relation Artwork-ArtCollection is defined in Artwork model:

```py
class Artwork(models.Model):
    ...
    art_collections = models.ManyToManyField("ArtCollection", related_name="artworks", blank=True)
```

According to the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ Adding a second time to m2m relation is OK, it will not duplicate the relation:

```
>>> a2.publications.add(p3)
```

but when I run

```
artwork = Artwork.objects.get(pk=1)
art_collection = ArtCollection.objects.get(pk=1)
artwork.art_collections.add(art_collection)
```

even when the relation already exists the .count() method returns count += 1 and I have duplicated relation (or multipled by 3, 4, 5 if I will countinue running .add(art_collection)
In shell I can clear the relations only by .clear() method, can not use artwork.art_collections.set([art_collection])

When I try to delete art_collections ids on admin panel (I have raw_id_field) - nothing happens. Those are my methods on ArtworkAdmin

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(ArtworkAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

what is interesting - form.cleaned_data['art_collections'] return qs with only one instance of ArtCollection - no matter if there are 5 when I clicked save button or 1 or 2 duplicated ids was deleted.

This is how the form looks:

```
from dal import autocomplete

class ArtWorkForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = (
            ...
            "art_collections",
        )
        widgets = {
            ...
        }
        help_texts = {
            ...
        }
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: What did you `.count()`, is it `artwork.art_collections.count()`? I couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: exactly
```In [2]: ac = ArtCollection.objects.last()
In [3]: ac.artworks.count()
Out[3]: 7
In [4]: art = ac.artworks.all()[1]
In [5]: art.art_collections.count()
Out[6]: 1```

Comment: `Out[6]: 1` is correct right? What's not expected?